# Is this a modal particle before a konjunktion?

Tags: subordinate-clause, modal-particle

> Aber er war nicht der Mann, der sofort um Hilfe rief, `nur` weil er etwas Seltsames in der Nacht wahrgenommen hatte, was genauso gut eine Täuschung sein konnte.

Is the reason why nur here can sit before the konjunktion is because it's a modal particle?

Comment: Focus particle + Subjunction 
Is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

That piece *nur weil* is a conjunction on its own. Similar are:

- und weil
- aber weil
- doch weil
- denn weil
- oder aber
- und wenn
- aber doch
- aber wenn
- nur wenn
  …

Comment: "Nur dass" is the only combination of "nur" with a subjunction that Duden lists as its own subjunction. Wonder why that is? The linguists at Duden must have had a good reason to exclude "nur weil" from the list. Is "nur" not rather a focus particle which is to the left of its scope which is the whole subordinate clause?

Comment: yea... the problem is I looked up "nur weil" on the webs before asking this question and there was no grammar website including it as a fixed conjunction (besides looking for all entries of 'nur' and 'weil' in Hammer's German and couldn't find this combination as a conjunction either)

Comment: Fortunately, most of those combinations you can understand literally: *nur weil — only/just because*.